# Iterated hash functions

Tags: hash, md5, compression-function

[image]

In this image, It describes the basic idea of an iterative hash function. I am confused as to why the `i` value is set to be `m+t+1` as default. Specifically, where does the `1` come from as m+t is just the arbitrary output size + `t` the message chunk size but the `1` im confused about

Comment: I'm struggling a bit with the question, do you have better definitions for the various variables? What is the source of this question? What does it have to do with md5 specifically?

Comment: It relates to the merkel damgard construction which is what MD5 is based on. m = internal state which is the preset value and t is the block size used in the iteration function as an iterative function processes the input in chunks.

Comment: Ah, I was wrong-footed by the question title: it indicates that the hash function is iterated (as in e.g. a password hash) instead of the compression function (usually just $F$ if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cases $i\le m+t$ can be handled with a single application of the $\mathsf{compress}$ function, which, pedantically speaking, would not be an iterated hash function.

Without seeing the rest of the article, it's hard to judge, but the both you and the author should beware the dangers of extending fixed length input functions to arbitrary length hash functions. It is quite easy to come up with an extension that allows trivial collisions by using padding schemes that give rise to collisions.